# Add Link To Image On Hover jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-masonry

I'm working on an image grid using jQuery and [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

I'm trying to achieve the following effects when a user hovers on an image in the grid:

1. A link shall appear when the mouse enters the element
2. The link shall disappear when the mouse leaves the element
3. The image should fade/skew to a greyish coloring scheme (not implemented here - wasn't sure how to approach it).

I've looked into [jQuery UI's Tooltips](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/), but these seem to work only in a "speech bubble" kind of way, when I'm interested for the link to appear on the image itself.

This is the code I've tried, using [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/), which just slaps the link next to the image.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.grid-item').hover(function(){
$(this).append($("<h1>This Will be A Link One Day</h1>"));
}, function(){
    $(this).find("h1:last").remove();
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is totally normal. You append a link and the the link is appended. If I get it right, what you want is to display an image (with a link) whenever a user hovers over you grid content. I suppose this is what you are looking for:

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#contentDiv").hover(function(){
            $("#imageDiv").html("<a href='yourlink.com'><img src='yourimage.png'</a>");
            $("#imageDiv").show();
       }, function(){
            $("#imageDiv").hide();
       });

       $("#contentDiv").mouseout(function(){
            $("#imageDiv").hide();
       });
});
```

HTML displayed in your grid (each row):

```
<div id="imageDiv">
</div>
<div id="contentDiv">
   Testing content, supposing is displayed in your grid
</div>
```

You can also check it out in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfyZU/2/). You could play with your test div dimensions and the picture to make it hover in a more stable fashion. I am just pointing out the idea.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks For Answering! However, this code doesn't work - both for me and in general. Check out this JFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/T3QtA//. Edited the question for more clarity.